# Surface Intersection on $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I just can't figure out how to solve this problem.

"Let $S=Z(xy-zw)\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ and $l \subset S$ a line. Show that does not exist any surface $S'\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ such that $S\cap S'=l$."

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Think about degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a surface would have some positive degree $d$.  What's the degree of $S$?  So what would that make the degree of $S \cap S'$?  This produces your contradiction.  (At least, provided we are interpreting the equation $S \cap S' = l$ scheme-theoretically.)